Событие нажатия на колесико мыши подключенной к телефону
Существует ли способ отловить событие нажатия на колесико мыши, подключенной к сенсорному устройству? Левую кнопку можно отловить через touchstart/touchend, правую через contextmenu. А колесико?

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/auxclick_event

Это не работает на сенсерном устройстве(

С чего бы ему там не работать?

@Qwertiy он хочет готовое решение...

@РезидентКазахстана, так это и есть готовое на такой вопрос.

Должны подойти события auxclick, mousedown и mouseup.
